# Where does caja put its preferences

Tags: debian, mate-desktop, caja, file-browser

I am running/using mate 1.20.2 amd using caja as my file and folder explorer (GUI-based) .

I have tried to figure out where caja puts it preferences but have failed.

```
$ caja --version
MATE caja 1.20.2
```

I tried to first see in .config/caja if it has what I'm looking for -

```
~/.config/mate$ ls
eom  panel2.d
```

Neither of the two folders had anything interesting contents.

Then I tried -

```
:~/.cache/mate$ ls
background
```

and even there I couldn't find any info.

I also looked at `dpkg -L caja` and saw `/usr/share/metainfo/caja.appdata.xml` but could not find anything which explains where it might be.

Even the F1 built right in caja doesn't tell anything .

Can somebody help to find out where it is ?

Comment: `$HOME/.config/caja/` : accels, desktop-metadata*

Comment: And at least some preferences are in the gsettings/dconf database.

Comment: but the "open with" configuration is not there either :(

Comment: that is what I was trying to say and I'm now at 1.20.4 . I guess we have to look at 1.22.x release or beyond for that feature.

Comment: oh no, not so long. mine is full of BS and almost unusable. I really need to clean this up!!!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this is a long answer. I hope you learn something from it, but I tried to most directly answer your question in the next paragraph and then use the rest of the answer to elaborate on what this means for editing settings outside the caja GUI itself.

A lot of caja's info and settings can usually be found stored in a `dconf` GVariant database (a binary file), the same as many other GUI programs use. The file is likely stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`.

Not all of Caja's functionality is changed using dconf (for instance, file associations are handled separately and independently of Caja itself [per freedesktop.org's specifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html)), but in a general sense the dconf database is likely where you need to be looking.

Note that the following presumes caja is using dconf, which is only true when `$GSETTINGS_BACKEND` is not set or is set to `dconf` in caja's environment (it uses dconf in probably at least 90% of all installs, and by default in Debian/Ubuntu/Mint). If the variable is set equal to `gconf`, the same basic idea applies but different tools are used and the settings are likely saved in XML files under `~/.gconf` instead of in a binary database.

For most users, `dconf` has largely replaced `gconf` for a few years and MATE uses `dconf` by default. One can also directly use the `gsettings` CLI tool to largely bypass this confusion (technically MATE is using gsettings (a part of [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/)), [which can use either](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/ch03.html)), but the dconf syntax is very nice. Nearly everyone using MATE will be using dconf, and this can be easily adapted to using `gconf` if necessary as it mostly works similarly from a user perspective.

You can use either a GUI like `dconf-editor` or a CLI program like `dconf` to manipulate dconf's database. For simple edits I tend to prefer the GUI, despite not being a huge fan of its Gnome3-style look (personally). However, the `dconf` CLI tool is quite handy if you want to use a text editor to tweak things or want to do changes programmatically. Thus, the following is a run-down on the `dconf` CLI tool and a few suggestions based on how I've used it in the past.

In Debian (and presumably Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and so forth), the `dconf-editor` GUI is in the `dconf-editor` package, while the CLI tool is in `dconf-cli`. In the distant past when I used Mint, this also was true.

For CLI usage, a few examples can be handy. So using `dconf` (the CLI tool), to dump all settings for caja, you can do

```
$ dconf dump /org/mate/caja/
```

Where `/org/mate/caja/` is the internal 'key' in the database file. Note that the `dconf` tool **requires** that all keys end with trailing slashes. If you want, you can redirect `dconf`'s output to a file, edit the file more traditionally, and then restore it:

```
$ dconf dump /org/mate/caja/ > cajaprefs.txt
$ $EDITOR cajaprefs.txt
$ dconf load /org/mate/caja/ < cajaprefs.txt
```

…Where `$EDITOR` is your editor of choice (I like emacs a lot, but the MATE default editor would be `pluma`).

Somewhat interestingly, `dconf load [PATH]` restores the data passed on `stdin`. Due to this, I use `<` to take input from a file, but one could also do `cat cajaprefs.txt | dconf load /org/mate/caja/`. My method simply avoids a `cat` process being spawned but they should both function the same way.

By substituting `/` for `/org/mate/caja/`, one could also export the entire database in text form. Note that this can potentially be dangerous if misused, but it's also quite handy sometimes for searching through the database.

You can also read or write an individual setting with single commands, such as:

```
$ dconf read /org/mate/caja/preferences/use-iec-units
false
$ dconf write /org/mate/caja/preferences/use-iec-units true
```

Note that I think you may have to restart caja for these settings to stick if applied outside its own GUI. It can vary between programs how they deal with manual changes to the dconf database. I use Caja, but within FVWM instead of MATE these days so it's possible some background service isn't running that would normally handle things like this.

`dconf help` or `dconf help [COMMAND]` can be useful in figuring out further usage.

Additionally, you can find the system-wide defaults and the general schema information in the system's schema directory. This is often either the value of `$GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR`, or usually `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.mate.caja.gschema.xml` if not set. Debian uses this path and so does Mint last I checked. These XML files also usually include a textual description of what various settings actually do, which is a handy reference point. You can also read the descriptions using external tools [like this one](https://github.com/jmatsuzawa/gsettings-info) if that's more your cup of tea than looking at XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is now in the mime configuration.
There are many locations which roughly relate to the number of repetitions in the open with dialog!
Probably the algorithm is not clean enough for the many repititions of the config file.

- /home/user/.config/mimeapps.list
- /home/user/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
- /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
- /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache
- /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
- /usr/share/mime/mime.cache

for xfce4 there is an extra app `/usr/bin/xfce4-mime-settings`

The way to get more insight is to check what the filemanager(caja) or the mime-settings app is reading:
`strace caja |& grep -E "stat|access|open" | grep -v ENOENT | grep mime`

however this is still a tedious job. I managed to move some config files out of the way and it got a bit better but not yet perfect :(

Comment: $HOME/.config/mimeapps.list  is the relevant information. I managed to open text/directory with my preferred app

Comment: Were they looking for default program settings? Because I don't see where they specified that in the question